# Javascript: Multiple checkboxes to be checked using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to get the second javascript line in this example to work (being able to select the check box from javascript):
http://jsfiddle.net/eTvDB/

Essentially, if I don't use xxx[] form for the name, I won't be able to obtain an array in PHP.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Well `elements["select2[]"].options[0]` doesn't make sense when `select2[]` is the name of some checkboxes and not the name of a select element. If the idea is to check the first checkbox with that name `document.forms["myForm"].elements["select2[]"][0].checked=true;` works. If the idea is to check _all_ of that name there are other ways to do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
document.myForm['select2[]'][0].checked = true;
```

Or

```
document.getElementsByName('select2[]')[0].checked = true;
```

***[The demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/eTvDB/1/)***